Measure of difficulty in pronouncing sounds
I came across this article that states that hunter gatherers found it more difficult to pronounce the f and v sounds. I was amused to find an exact percentage given in the article:
"While the hunter-gatherers’ tooth formation would have made it easier to tear into harder foods, it also would have made the “F” and “V” sounds about 30% more difficult, according to the study...."
How is the difficulty of pronouncing sounds calculated? Are there studies that measure this for other sounds? I also assume the difficulty would vary across populations?

I've seen this claim before and I'm extremely skeptical seeing as they seem to ignore the existence of bilabial fricatives which are not affected by this argument and which are almost impossible to distinguish from labiodental fricatives in reconstruction

What an interesting find!
Here's the study they're citing, which says specifically:

Biomechanical models of the speech apparatus show that labiodentals incur about 30% less muscular effort in the overbite and overjet configuration than in the edge-to-edge bite configuration.

All right, so what is "muscular effort"? This is discussed around figure 3:

Sum of the total muscle force expressed as a percentage of the total maximum force of all muscles in the model.

So they're doing simulations of how much physical force the muscles need to exert to create these sounds, and comparing that total amount of force between different jaw arrangements.
